# Boolean mask for lists as entries in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, masking

I have a pandas DataFrame that contains lists as entries

```
data = {'col1': [
['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 
['cat', 'dog', 'horse'], 
[1, 2, 3]
]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I then want to return rows using boolean mask IF 'foo' is in the list of any row (in this case, row 0).  The following will return an empty DataFrame:

```
df[df['col1'] == 'foo']
```

The best way I can achieve the above is the following:

```
df[df['col1'].apply(lambda x: True if 'foo' in x else False)]
```

but I feel like there is a way to simplify this code.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, use `lambda x: 'foo' in x`.

Comment: Ah yes thank you.  I'm actually gonna modify the question as I realize this wasn't the problem i was trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

As Henry already posted in the comments, you can shrink the code, if you use `'foo' in x` inside lambda.
To me, this looks pythonic enough.

The complete line would be

```
df[df["col1"].apply(lambda x: 'foo' in x)]
```

If you want to avoid the lambda expression you can use:

```
def inside(my_list, key): return key in my_list
out = df[df["col1"].apply(inside, key="foo")]
```

This uses a function defined in advance, which could be extended. This is not possible with the lambda expression.